# how to change dropdown menu before scraping using beautiuflSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape hourly weather data for the month of January in 2022. I found this [website](https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/saudi-arabia/riyadh/historic?month=1&year=2022) that has a table that lists temprature per hour. The problem is, the website has one url link for the whole month, and there is a dropdown box where you can select the day you want.

So far, I can only webscrape the first day of January (which is the default option in the dropdown box) but I don't know how to change the option to get data for the rest of the months.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuMd5.png)

This is the code I used to webscrape the table for January1, 2022

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 

url = 'https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/saudi-arabia/riyadh/historic?month=1&year=2022'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')



df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Time', 'Temp', 'Weather', 'Wind', 'Humidity'])
table = soup.find('table', id='wt-his')
date = table.tbody.find_all('tr')[0].find('th').text.strip()[5:]

for row in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):    
    # Find all data for each column
    Time = row.find('th').text.strip()
    # date = row[0].find('th').text.strip()[5:]
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    if(columns != []):
        time = Time
        temp = columns[1].text.strip()
        weather = columns[2].text.strip()
        wind = columns[3].text.strip()
        humidity = columns[5].text.strip()
        df = df.append({'Date': date, 'Time': time[:5], 'Temp': temp, 'Weather': weather, 'Wind':wind, 'Humidity':humidity}, ignore_index = True)
```

can anyone help please

Comment: that dropdown just changes the month and year url parameters and then does a reload. Something wrong with doing that yourself ?

Comment: @rasjani the dropdown I am trying to change is the second one in the page right before the table, which changes the day not the month, and changing its value does now change the url

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from external URL via Ajax. To parse it you can try:

```py
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://www.timeanddate.com/scripts/cityajax.php"

params = {
    "n": "saudi-arabia/riyadh",
    "mode": "historic",
    "hd": "20230304",
    "month": "3",
    "year": "2023",
    "json": "1",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).text
data = json.loads(re.sub(r'([csh]):', r'"\1":', data))

all_data = []
for column in data:
    row = [row['h'] for row in column['c']]
    all_data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser').get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser').img['title'])
df[2] = df[2].apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser').text)
df[5] = df[5].apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser').span['title'])
df[8] = df[8].str.replace('&nbsp;', ' ')

df.columns = 'Time Condition Temp Weather Wind1 Wind2 Humidity Barometer Visibility'.split()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   Time          Condition   Temp            Weather   Wind1                                                      Wind2 Humidity  Barometer Visibility
0   12:00 am Sat, Mar 4             Clear.  70 °F             Clear.   6 mph  Wind blowing from 150° South-southeast to North-northwest      29%  30.18 "Hg      10 mi
1               1:00 am             Clear.  68 °F             Clear.   7 mph  Wind blowing from 160° South-southeast to North-northwest      26%  30.18 "Hg      10 mi
2               2:00 am             Clear.  68 °F             Clear.   9 mph                      Wind blowing from 170° South to North      24%  30.15 "Hg      10 mi
3               4:00 am             Clear.  66 °F             Clear.   6 mph                      Wind blowing from 170° South to North      28%  30.15 "Hg      10 mi
4               5:00 am             Clear.  64 °F             Clear.   5 mph  Wind blowing from 160° South-southeast to North-northwest      34%  30.15 "Hg      10 mi
5               6:00 am             Clear.  64 °F             Clear.   5 mph  Wind blowing from 150° South-southeast to North-northwest      30%  30.18 "Hg      10 mi
6               7:00 am             Sunny.  63 °F             Sunny.   5 mph              Wind blowing from 130° Southeast to Northwest      37%  30.21 "Hg      10 mi
7               8:00 am             Sunny.  68 °F             Sunny.   2 mph  Wind blowing from 150° South-southeast to North-northwest      35%  30.21 "Hg      10 mi
8               9:00 am             Sunny.  75 °F             Sunny.  13 mph                      Wind blowing from 180° South to North      19%  30.21 "Hg      10 mi
9              10:00 am             Sunny.  79 °F             Sunny.  10 mph                      Wind blowing from 180° South to North      18%  30.21 "Hg      10 mi
10             11:00 am             Sunny.  81 °F             Sunny.   8 mph  Wind blowing from 200° South-southwest to North-northeast      18%  30.21 "Hg      10 mi
11             12:00 pm  Scattered clouds.  82 °F  Scattered clouds.   6 mph                      Wind blowing from 180° South to North      20%  30.18 "Hg        N/A
12              1:00 pm  Scattered clouds.  86 °F  Scattered clouds.   6 mph                      Wind blowing from 170° South to North      18%  30.15 "Hg        N/A
13              2:00 pm             Sunny.  88 °F             Sunny.   6 mph  Wind blowing from 150° South-southeast to North-northwest      17%  30.12 "Hg      10 mi
14              3:00 pm             Sunny.  88 °F             Sunny.   6 mph              Wind blowing from 130° Southeast to Northwest      17%  30.09 "Hg      10 mi
15              4:00 pm             Sunny.  88 °F             Sunny.   7 mph              Wind blowing from 140° Southeast to Northwest      18%  30.09 "Hg      10 mi
16              5:00 pm             Sunny.  86 °F             Sunny.   7 mph              Wind blowing from 130° Southeast to Northwest      17%  30.12 "Hg      10 mi
17              6:00 pm             Clear.  82 °F             Clear.   6 mph    Wind blowing from 120° East-southeast to West-northwest      21%  30.12 "Hg      10 mi
18              7:00 pm             Clear.  79 °F             Clear.   5 mph              Wind blowing from 130° Southeast to Northwest      28%  30.12 "Hg      10 mi
19              8:00 pm             Clear.  77 °F             Clear.   6 mph              Wind blowing from 130° Southeast to Northwest      26%  30.15 "Hg      10 mi
20              9:00 pm             Clear.  77 °F             Clear.   6 mph              Wind blowing from 140° Southeast to Northwest      24%  30.15 "Hg      10 mi
21             10:00 pm             Clear.  75 °F             Clear.   5 mph  Wind blowing from 160° South-southeast to North-northwest      27%  30.18 "Hg      10 mi
22             11:00 pm             Clear.  73 °F             Clear.   5 mph              Wind blowing from 140° Southeast to Northwest      31%  30.18 "Hg      10 mi
```